# Typo3 Fluid - Add Counter in dynamic Form

Tags: fluid, typo3-7.6.x, view-helpers

simply i just want to have a counter that starts at 0 and gets incremented everytime the if-condition inside my for each is true. 
I know how to achieve this in javascript .. 
The countervar should stay in front of **Entry** inside the Label.

```
<f:for each="{house.offers}" as="offer" key="index">
            <f:if condition="{offer.offerCategory} == {category}">
                <f:then>
                    <div class="form-element-wrap removable">
                        <label class="label" for="{index}"> **Entry** for {category.title}</label>
                        <f:form.hidden name="house[offers][{index}][__identity]" value="{offer.uid}" />
                        <f:form.textfield name="house[offers][{index}][title]" id="{index}" class="text form-element" value="{offer.title}" />
                        <button class="remove-button" role="button" aria-label="delete-button"></button>
                    </div>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <f:form.hidden name="house[offers][{index}][__identity]" value="{offer.uid}" />
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
```

Comment: You could use the VHS package. It have many clever viewhelpers. for example this one: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Math/SumViewHelper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to TYPO3v8 you could use `EXT:vhs` which gives you a viewhelper to set Fluid variables.

The calculation could be done via TypoScript then:

```xml
<v:variable.set name="counter"><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.calc" data="{counter} + 1" /></v:variable.set>
```

```
lib.calc = TEXT
lib.calc.current = 1
lib.calc.prioriCalc = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Fluid in TYPO3v8 and newer [supports variables which are set at runtime](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/7712d383a947333be3291d9e9b1630d44275c563/src/ViewHelpers/VariableViewHelper.php) when rendering a template. It also [supports basic math](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/7712d383a947333be3291d9e9b1630d44275c563/examples/Resources/Private/Singles/Math.html) so you should be able to achieve what you need this way:

```xml
<f:variable name="counter">0</f:variable>

<f:for ...>
    <f:if ...>
        <f:variable name="counter">{counter + 1}</f:variable>
        {counter}
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: After editing my code i got following error message: "Could not analyse class: "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\VariableViewHelper" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\VariableViewHelper does not exist"

Comment: This viewhelper is available only since TYPO3 9. Please add a tag to your question specifying the version of your TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, f:variable only works since [version 8](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79402-VariableViewHelperForFluid.html).
Before that, it needed the vhs extension with the following namespace:

`{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}`

And then you can use the variables.

`<v:variable.set name="counter" value="0" />`

`{counter}`